# Python: How do you determine if a list of unordered tuples is IN a dictionaries.values()?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Im trying to iterate through one dictionary and determine if during iteration the value is present in a second dictionary. The values are lists with tuple coordinates at list items. When I run the following expected results don't return. What could I be doing wrong?

---

```
o={123:[(2045414.2025330812, 737011.67879535258), (2045345.5412850082, 736965.27060331404)]}
t={234:[(2053962.2499010414, 731325.2501180619), (2053955.6251330376, 731121.18739786744)]}
y={345:[(2045414.2025330812, 737011.67879535258), (2045345.5412850082, 736965.27060331404)]}
h={456:[(2045345.5412850082, 736965.27060331404), (2045414.2025330812, 737011.67879535258)]}


for k, v in o.items():
    if v in h.values():
        print k, v
```

Comment: The value of `o`is not in `h`. `if v in y.values():` will return something. The order matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an ordered list of tuples. To compare an unordered collection of tuples, you can use `set`:

```
for k, v in o.items():
    if set(v).issubset(set(next(iter(h.values())))):
        print(k, v)

123 [(2045414.2025330812, 737011.6787953526), (2045345.5412850082, 736965.270603314)]
```

An alternative way of writing the above logic:

```
for k, v in o.items():
    if set(v) <= set(list(h.values())[0]):
        print(k, v)
```

The tricky part is converting `dict.values()` to a `set`. Since `h` only has one value, you need to extract the only value before conversion to `set`.

Comment: I should have indicated earlier but the code I shared is an over simplified example of the problem i'm facing. The Dictionaries will have multiple key/ value pairs to check against. The solution you provided does work if the dictionary only has one key but I couldn't get it to work with multiple

Comment: @JeffLong, Given you have 2 answers here, can you post a separate question with another minimal (and representative!) example? You can mock up some simple data, e.g. a float can just be `1.5` instead of `435235235.4325325432532565`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the list of tuples is itself unordered, then perhaps that is the problem in that you are comparing `v` to something in `h.values()`, but where `h.values()` has the list in a different order. Why not simply store sets as the values?

```
checker = set(list(map(set, h.values))
for k, v in o.items():
    if set(v) in checker:
        print(k,v)
```

Perhaps you can create your data structures in this format to avoid the unnecessary overhead.